# Get CGPoint in comparison to app Window

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview

I have a tableview. I want to find the center of the UIImageView for the appDelegates window.

```
MA_MobileAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MA_MobileAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

            UAModalPanel *modalPanel = [[MSPicturePreview alloc] initWithFrame:appDelegate.window.frame withimage:self.customImageView.image];

            [appDelegate.window addSubview:modalPanel];

            [modalPanel showFromPoint:[appDelegate.window.superview convertPoint:[self.customImageView center] toView:nil]];
```

The code below makes the point at the top left. Any way to get the actual point of the image on the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this

```
[modalPanel showFromPoint:[self.contentView convertPoint:[self.customImageView center] toView:appDelegate.window]];
```

Basically I used the cells contentView to convert the point for the appDelegates window...

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. I think it will work.

```
[modalPanel showFromPoint:[self.view convertPoint:[self.customImageView center] toView:appDelegate.window.superview];
```